# Quiero hacer una condicional con un Date que muestre un mensaje al seleccionar una fecha que sobrepase la actual

Tags: javascript, html

Aquí trato de realizar mi formulario, pero aún no comprendo del todo como realizar el condicional con `Date` para que me salga ese mensaje y pueda asi realizar la validacion igual que las otras entradas de datos.Quisiera alguna alternativa en la cual se lograra el resultado que espero con el tipo `Date`, sigo buscando información pero no encuentro una solución, adjunto mi intento fallido:

```js
function validarForm() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
    var correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
    var fecha_nacimiento = document.getElementById("fecha_nacimiento").value;

    let formatMail = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;

    if (nombre.trim().length == 0 || apellido.trim().length == 0 ||
        correo.trim().length == 0 || fecha_nacimiento.trim().length == 0) {
        alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios y no deben ser vacios.");
        return false;

    } else if (!formatMail.test(correo)) {
        alert("El correo no tiene un formato valido.");
        return false;

    } else if (!Date.toLocaleDateString(fecha_nacimiento)) {
        alert("No puede seleccionar una fecha futura");
        return false;

    } else {
        alert("Datos guardados correctamente");
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>Validación</h2>
<form onsubmit="return validarForm()">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="correo">Correo:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" >
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahora explicalo como si fueramos extraños que no tienen idea de lo que estas haciendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Capturas el valor del input `fecha_nacimiento` en el formato correspondiente:

  ```
  var fechaSeleccionada = new Date(fecha_nacimiento);
  ```
- Capturas la fecha actual:

  ```
  var fechaActual = new Date();
  ```
- Luego validas si la fecha capturada es mayor a la fecha actual. Si cumple, muestra la alerta y retorna `false`. Si no cumple el `if`, quiere decir que todos los campos fueron validados correctamente y se envía tu formulario.

  ```
  if (fechaSeleccionada > fechaActual) {
    alert("No puede seleccionar una fecha futura.");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Datos guardados correctamente.");
  }
  ```

#### Demo:

```js
function validarForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
  var correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
  var fecha_nacimiento = document.getElementById("fecha_nacimiento").value;

  let formatMail = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;

  if (nombre.trim().length == 0 || apellido.trim().length == 0 ||
      correo.trim().length == 0 || fecha_nacimiento.trim().length == 0) {
    alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios y no deben ser vacios.");
    return false;

  } else if (!formatMail.test(correo)) {
    alert("El correo no tiene un formato valido.");
    return false;

  } else {
    var fechaSeleccionada = new Date(fecha_nacimiento);
    var fechaActual = new Date();

    if (fechaSeleccionada > fechaActual) {
      alert("No puede seleccionar una fecha futura.");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("Datos guardados correctamente.");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Validación</h2>
  <form onsubmit="return validarForm(event)">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="correo">Correo:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" >
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Métodos nativos

Puedes usar los métodos `getMonth()`, `getDate()` y `getFullYear()` del objeto `Date`.

A continuación, te proporciono una descripción de cada uno:

- `getMonth()` es un método nativo de todos los objetos `Date`, que sirve para obtener el número de mes en el que está la fecha. **A considerar: El método devuelve el mes restado a uno, es decir, *Enero*, que es el primer mes del año será `0` para este método.**
- `getDate()` también es nativo, sirve para obtener el día de la fecha.
- `getFullYear()` es nativo de igual manera. Sirve para obtener el año de la fecha.

Dicho esto, la lógica que utilizaremos será muy simple:

- Obtendremos la fecha desde el `<input>`. **Ten en cuenta que al ser un `<input>` de tipo `date`, al obtener la propiedad `value`, estará como un `string`. Así que usaremos el constructor `Date` para obtener la fecha y poder aplicar los métodos mencionados.**
- Comparamos el año con el año actual. Si el año seleccionado es mayor al año actual, entonces, descartamos la fecha, si es igual o menor tendremos que hacer algunas comparaciones extra.
- Si el año es menor, no hay problema.
- Si el año es igual, entonces tendremos que comparar el mes de la fecha con el mes actual, seguiremos un patrón.
- Si el mes es mayor al mes actual, también descartamos la fecha.
- Si es menor, no habría problema.
- Si es igual, tenemos que comparar el día de la fecha.
- Si el día es mayor al día actual, descartamos la fecha.
- Si el día es igual al día actual, podríamos considerar la fecha, pero depende de ti si la quieres considerar.
- Si el día es menor, la fecha es válida.

A continuación, tienes un ejemplo aplicando toda esta lógica.

```js
function validarForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    let apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
    let correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
    let fecha_nacimiento = new Date(document.getElementById("fecha_nacimiento").value);
    const dateNow = new Date();
    const dayNow = dateNow.getDate();
    const monthNow = dateNow.getMonth();
    const yearNow = dateNow.getFullYear();

    let formatMail = /\w+@\w+\.+[a-z]/;

    if (nombre.trim().length == 0 || apellido.trim().length == 0 ||
        correo.trim().length == 0 || (fecha_nacimiento instanceof Date && isNaN(fecha_nacimiento) )) {
        alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios y no deben ser vacios.");
        return false;
    }
    
    if (!formatMail.test(correo)) {
        alert("El correo no tiene un formato valido.");
        return false;
    }
    
    const dateBorn_year = fecha_nacimiento.getFullYear();
    const dateBorn_day = fecha_nacimiento.getDate()+1;
    const dateBorn_month = fecha_nacimiento.getMonth();
    
    if (dateBorn_year > yearNow) {
       alert("Fecha futura inválida.");
       return false;
    }
    
    if (dateBorn_year === yearNow) {
     if (dateBorn_month > monthNow) {
      alert("Fecha futura inválida.");
       return false;
     }
     
     if (dateBorn_month === monthNow) {
      if (dateBorn_day > dayNow) {
        alert("Fecha futura inválida.");
        return false;
      }
     }
    }
    
    alert("Datos guardados correctamente");
}

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", validarForm);
```

```html
<h2>Validación</h2>
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="correo">Correo:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo"> 
    <br><br>
    <label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" >
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

He tenido las siguientes consideraciones respecto a tu código inicial:

- **Usar métodos `on`**: Este tipo de métodos incluidos en el HTML directamente puede dificultar la comprensión del código, por lo que te recomiendo separar la lógica de la estructura. Para lograr esto, he usado `addEventListener`
- **La página se refresca**: Como ves, al ser tu etiqueta un `<form>`, al hacerle `submit`, la página siempre se va a refrescar, independientemente de si aparezca la alerta o no. Para manejar esto, he usado `event.preventDefault()`.
- **Validación de la fecha**: He usado `isNaN` para obtener fechas inválidas. Estos casos pueden ocurrir cuando el usuario deja en blanco el campo de fecha.

En este enfoque, usamos el constructor `Date` dos veces. La primera es para obtener la fecha en base a la entrada del usuario, cuando usamos `new Date(document.getElementById("fecha_nacimiento").value)`, obtenemos el valor del campo de fecha, y luego lo convertirnos a un objeto `Date` para poder procesarlo. Luego, usamos los métodos nativos en `dateBorn_year`, `dateBorn_month` y `dateBorn_day` para poder interpretar la fecha.

Luego de esto usamos el constructor `new Date()` nuevamente, para obtener la fecha y hora de hoy día. Luego definimos `dateNow`, `monthNow`, `dayNow` y `yearNow` que representan el día, fecha y hora actuales.

Después de todo esto, empezamos a comparar. Puedes detenerte a analizar el código si así lo gustas, sin embargo, aquí te lo explico paso a paso.

- **Primer Criterio: Si el año es menor, no hay problema.** Esto se ve expresado en esta línea de código:

```js
if (dateBorn_year > yearNow) { ... }
```

Esto lo que hace es comparar si es año dado en la fecha es mayor al año actual, si es así, la fecha es inválida.

- **Segundo Criterio: Si el año es igual, entonces tendremos que comparar el mes de la fecha con el mes actual, seguiremos un patrón.** Esto se ve expresado en esta línea de código:

```js
if (dateBorn_year === yearNow) {
    if (dateBorn_month > monthNow) {
        ...
    }

    if (dateBorn_month === monthNow) {
        if (dateBorn_day > dayNow) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Primero, comparamos el año actual con el año dado, si son iguales, procedemos, sino, ya hicimos lo correspondiente en el **primer criterio**.

Luego, comprobaremos si el mes dado en la fecha es mayor al mes actual, si lo es, podemos deducir que la fecha también es inválida, para esto tenemos esta línea de código.

```js
if (dateBorn_month > monthNow) { ... }
```

Y por último, si no pasó nada en el anterior criterio, comprobaremos el día, si el día es mayor al día actual, podemos deducir también que la fecha es inválida. Esto se ve en la siguiente línea.

```js
if (dateBorn_day > dayNow) { ... }
```

Si todas estas comprobaciones fueron exitosas, eso quiere decir que la fecha debería de ser válida.

---

### Consideraciones

Que el cliente envíe la solicitud a tu servidor, no quiere decir que sea la única manera en la que se pueda hacer. Probablemente hayas oído de peticiones que se bloquean por *CORS*. Si bien, la respuesta del servidor no estará disponible, eso no significa que el servidor no haya procesado la solicitud. De esta manera, un atacante puede vulnerar tu sistema, porque si bien se realizan validaciones desde el cliente, si se envía la petición de otra parte, no hay filtros, a menos que los tengas del lado del servidor. Aquí te dejo unas consideraciones adicionales que es muy importante tener en cuenta.

- **Filtra las entradas:** Para evitar código malicioso y posibles vulneraciones, es crucial que filtres las entradas desde el servidor y compruebes que tengan una forma consistente, como el email, la fecha, etc. Si un atacante logra burlar el sistema porque no hay ningún control, es posible que envíes alguna consulta a tu base de datos, y ahí surja una vulnerabilidad.
- **Uas consultas preparadas:** Si usas bases de datos SQL en tu app, es importante usar consultas preparadas, porque esto hará que se separen los datos de lo que realmente se debe interpretar como instrucciones.
- **Usa HTTPS:** Es crucial que uses algoritmos de cifrado fuertes como lo es el HTTPS, de esta manera los datos que envíes al servidor siempre viajarán cifrados. Esto evita ataques **"Man-in-the-middle"**.

---

### Enlaces de interés y referencias

- [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)
- [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [`Date() constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)
- [`Date.prototype.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)
- [`Date.prototype.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)
- [`Date.prototype.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)
- [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)
- [¿Qué es la inyección de SQL y cómo funciona?](https://www.avast.com/es-es/c-sql-injection)
- [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)